# Check value to disable/enable Context Menu Item (android)

Tags: android, contextmenu

In my application has a ListView. When long press on item the "Context Menu" will appear. I want to check the data ID, then set disable/enable to my Context Menu "Items". I can not find out the function like getMenuInfo() or something like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu , View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{       
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);       
    menu.add(0, ADD_FAVORITE_ID, 0, "Check");       
    menu.add(0, ADD_FAVORITE_ID, 0, "UnCheck").setEnabled(false);                       
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo();
```

Then, `info.id` is the `_ID` of whatever item was long-tapped in your ListView.

Comment: Thanks for your code, It work! and the correct syntax is "menuInfo" ---> AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;